# apt-get fails with raspberry pi although ping works

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, apt-get

I'm trying to update and install stuff with my raspberry pi.

Unfortunately it's failing, and I get these errors when doing `sudo apt-get update` :

```
Err http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy Release.gpg
 Could not resolve 'host'
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy Release.gpg
 Could not resolve 'host'
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy Release.gpg
 Could not resolve 'host'
Err http://repository.wolfram.com wheezy Release.gpg
 Could not resolve 'host'
```

And a few more lines like that...
The weird thing is that if I ping those addresses I get a response, so my DNS is probably ok:

```
ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org
```

Any other ideas why this would fail ? and of course, how can i fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend you to edit /etc/apt/sources.list with your favorite text editor **in root** (nano,vim,...), and writing this :

```
#deb mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

The # sign is just the way to commenting out a line in sources.list

When your done, download the public key and install it with this command :

```
wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian.public.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

If there is any problem, send the output :).

Good luck

Comment: This kinda worked! thanks. Seems like it's updating and installing correctly, but i get this line now: `sudo: unable to resolve host raspberrypi`

Comment: BTW, can you add a few words about what does this actually do?

Comment: The sources.list is where apt will find all packages you need. So, when you type in `apt-get install nano`, he will search nano in http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian.

The last line is to download a key to verify each download you make via apt.